# Can't get proxying a websocket working with create-react-app

Tags: websocket, proxy, create-react-app

I created a CRA in a docker container and I'm trying to proxy websockets over to another container running a python backend. I for the life of me cannot get the connection working.

I have verified that the server works by exposing the port *outside* of docker and connecting to it from the browser directly - it connects and works.

I can also verify that the connection *within* my CRA docker is set up properly - within it I start up a shell and do

```
> WS = require('ws')
> new WS(`ws://server:8765/ws/foo`).addEventListener('open', e => console.log('open'))
```

and that connects and prints `open` too. (This is why I don't have the `docker` tag on here, from my understanding this eliminates docker from being a possible issue since I've confirmed I can connect from one to the other)

The only thing that I can think of is that the proxy configuration is wrong

Here's what I'm trying to do on the client

```
const socket = new WebSocket(`ws:localhost/ws/foo`)
```

my proxy setup

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware")

module.exports = (app) => {
as I can tell. Need to circle back
    app.use(`/ws*`, proxy({
        target: 'ws://server:8765/ws',
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true,
    }))
}
```

I have tried that with `/ws` and with putting the url in the `proxy` clause instead o the `use` and...still nothing

I'm really not sure what more I can be missing.

Here are my dependency versions

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
        "react": "^16.10.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
        "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
        "styled-components": "^4.4.0"
    },
```